# Serve Downloads from Directory using Angular

Tags: angular, file-sharing

I have a list of documents in the same folder I'm serving my Angular application from. I want to make a webpage that shows a list of the documents, and links to download individual ones.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is generally advisable to serve docs through your own backend,but you could simplify that effort by using some standard angular packages. Below are some of the options:

1. [ngx-doc-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer) - Probably the best library and support a lot of file types. This [demo](https://angular-doc-viewer.firebaseapp.com/) can help you know it better.
2. [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer) - When your concerns are limited to pdf, this is a much simpler package to use, but do not have a wide range of customizations.[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-pdf-viewer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
3. [ngx-extended-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer) - This has a wide range of customizations and can be really cool if your concerns are regarding doc display with a toolbar.[Demo](https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/simple)
4. NodeJs + DB - Last but not least, the most customizable and standard approach for complex applications would be building your own backend. The backend server can actually be allocated a folder for docs, and the documents can be uploaded/saved by users/admin in that specific folder.

Comment: I'm not against making a small NodeJs app to serve the files. I just figured it was super overkill for just wanting to offer some download links. Thanks for the list of options!